# React JS odd Error on 'npm start' Failed to parse source map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio, socket.io

My Error:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/base64-arraybuffer/dist/base64-arraybuffer.es5.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'C:\Users\userName\Documents\folder\subFolder\client\node_modules\src\index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\userName\Documents\folder\subFolder\client\node_modules\src\index.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/decodePacket.browser.js 2:0-44 38:20-26
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-parser/build/esm/index.js 2:0-45 27:26-38 39:0-68
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-client/build/esm/socket.js 6:0-44 113:16-24 586:18-26
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-client/build/esm/index.js 1:0-37 2:0-18 3:24-39
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-client/build/esm/manager.js 1:0-75 23:4-25 116:22-28
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-client/build/esm/index.js 2:0-39 26:13-20 29:22-29 45:2-9 63:0-79
 @ ./src/pages/playArea/sidebar/Sidebar.jsx 8:0-38 47:14-16
 @ ./src/pages/playArea/PlayArea.jsx 12:0-40 126:39-46
 @ ./src/App.js 11:0-49 29:38-46 40:38-46
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 16:39-42
```

I only receive this error in recent React projects which is very odd. From the error message, I assume that either I misspelled the .js extension as .ts or React is just a bit broken, .

Everything runs and my website application runs perfectly fine but I don't like to see any errors in my projects. I have ctrl+f searched through all of my files and nowhere so I include the .ts extension so I am at a loss. If it matters, I run my website application on Visual Studio Code using my localhost.

-It may be an issue with my socket.io but I have no idea what could be wrong.
-It shouldn't have anything to do with my index.js either as I stripped that down to only `render <App />`

If you have any idea how to fix this issue or further troubleshooting steps that I can take, I would like to hear them.

Comment: Seems it doesn't break anything, other than that irritating long warning.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't deployed anything to my host yet, just localhost but nothing seems wrong so far. I just don't like to have any warnings since false warnings may hide actual issues.

Answer (score 2):

Its a recently raised issue in socket.io-client (https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1520). I had the same issue, downgrading socket.io-client 4.0.4 to 4.0.0 made the error go away.